# Get all the points in triangular ROI in a xy plane

Tags: matlab, math, opencv, roi

Input: I have some 50000 points in a xy plane as shown in the below picture.

Now, I need to get all the possible points in a triangular ROI. How to get it. It can can be opencv or Matlab.

The below is the sample where I need to get the possible points of the triangular areas.

[image]

Comment: Do you select these interactively or just have the triangles?

Comment: Interactively.. I have the (x y) of the vertices of the triangular ROI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MATLAB has an `inpolygon` command: [inpolygon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html).

For example, this code

```
 xv = [0.1 0.4 0.15 0.1]; yv = [0 0.4 0.8 0];
 x = rand(250,1); y = rand(250,1);
 in = inpolygon(x,y,xv,yv);
 plot(xv,yv,x(in),y(in),'r+',x(~in),y(~in),'bo')
```

generates a picture like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there a similar function in OpenCV...??

Comment: @ Kavka :: Thanks for the example... Can you let me know OpenCV equivalent of inpolygon... I can accept the answer...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know OpenCV.

Comment: @2vision2 didn't you ask "It can can be opencv or Matlab." :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, in c++?

```
Mat plane = imread("plane.png"); // this is the 50 000 pixel plane image

// I assume your triangles are here. E.e. findContours function would save them here, but I don't know your situation.
vector<vector<Point> > triangles;

// this size is something like 1000, so here are only points that should be checkedd if they are inside some triangle
    vector<Point> points; 

// lets loop all rois and check if point is inside one of them
for (int j = 0; j < triangles.size(); j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
     double test = pointPolygonTest(trigangles[j], points[i] false);
     if (test < 0) {
      cout << " point " << points[i] << " is outside of triangle " << j << endl;
     } else if (test > 0) {
      cout << " point " << points[i] << " is inside of triangle " << j << endl;
     } else if (test == 0) {
      cout << " point " << points[i] << " is on edge of triangle " << j << endl;
     }
    }
}
```

for more info: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest

here is OpenCV's example: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/point_polygon_test/point_polygon_test.html

Comment: Can we do it without a for loop?? I have 50,000 points in the plane

Comment: Is amount of points _inside_ triangels 50 000 or in whole image?

Comment: no..50,000 points in the plane and may be some 1000 points in each triangle

Comment: Ya..I got the pointPolygonTest..can you comment on -- if I can avoid the for loop for the 50k points ....and Thanks again

Comment: you can't change the fact, that you'll have to look at all 50000 points, to see if they're "in" or "out". so having a function that hides the loop or not does not make a difference. (ok, cleaner code. but..)

Comment: That's true. Well i don't know if asker knows triangle positions or not. If he know them he doesn't need to loop 50 000 points. Only points he want to check if one point is inside a triangle or not.

Comment: @break :: Correct ..But like in Matlab there might be a possibility to deal in one line for all the points... like in the answer given by kavka

Comment: @iiro :: I know the position (x y) of the triangles..Now for each triangle...I have to check which of the 50k points lie inside the triangle...

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV, you can quickly filter out the points that are not in the minimal bounding rectangle for each triangle. This rectangle can be previously computed by hand or with [cv::boundingRect()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=rect#boundingrect). The hit test is done with [Rect::contains()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Rect_). This is a fast operation (at least much faster than cv::pointPolygonTest)and this will filter out the points that are obviously not in any triangle. Afterward, you test the points that pass the filter with [cv::pointPolygonTest()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=rect#pointpolygontest).

That is:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> pointList;
std::vector<cv::Rect> rectList;
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> triangleList;

for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < pointList.size(); pointIndex++)
{
  for (int rectIndex = 0; rectIndex < rectList.size(); rectIndex++)
  {
    if (!rectList[rectIndex].contains(pointList[pointIndex]))
      continue;

    if (cv::pointPolygonTest(triangleList[rectIndex], pointList[pointIndex], false) < 0)
      continue;

    /* TODO Mark the point for future use */
  }
}
```