# How do I linear blend an image to a portion of the image only?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was able to linear blend the beamwidth with the 2D occupancy grid map by resizing the beamwidth to the size of the 2D occupancy grid map, transform the beamwidth corresponding to the camera's pose and blending the two images as the requirement of the function is to have both images the same size.

However, it blurs the entire map even with an alpha of 0.9

Is it possible to apply linear blend only the portion of the map that the beamwidth (triangle) covers? How?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Find Region of Interest ofg the triangle:

    Mat image = imread("");
    Rect region_of_interest = Rect(x, y, w, h);
    Mat image_roi = image(region_of_interest);

Apply bluring to image_roi

place the image_roi back into the original image
```

Comment: Is there no way for the triangle will only be blended? And not a rectangular matrix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104780/get-all-the-points-in-triangular-roi-in-a-xy-plane

Comment: I just did a linear blending for each pixel inside the triangle ROI. Still, thanks for your answer :)